# Android buttons not aligning properly on different phones

Tags: android, button, alignment

I have following 4 buttons on android phone:

```
ButtonA ButtonB
ButtonC ButtonD
```

They show up like this on android 2 buttons on each line. On smaller phone screen it work perfect. But on bigger phone screens it only shows two top button and seems like bottom 2 buttons are hidden. Can anyone please tell how to set these buttons so that it display same for all screen sizes?

Comment: please explain in details.. let us know how you designed xml layout..

Comment: What kind of layout you use to arrange your buttons?

Comment: @user1161518 - hi i am using linear

Comment: paste your code then it became easy to diagnose what's going wrong?

Comment: can you add xml file you are using

Comment: @NoviceMe Were you able to resolve this issue?